Purpose of VDD_SPI pin for ESP32-S3-MINI
I'm using ESP32-S3FN8 for a custome-made ESP32 PCB. I'm using the schematic for ESP32-S3-Mini-1 as a reference since it uses that IC.
One pin is still confusing me and that's VDD_SPI. From what I learned from the datasheet this pin is primarily used to supply power to an external flash memory.
According to the ESP32-S3-MINI schematics it's connected to two capacitors but nothing else??
Why not just leave it floating?

https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3-mini-1_mini-1u_datasheet_en.pdf

This might be something you need to ask from the manufacturer to get a specific answer.
But in general, it's a voltage output that has selectable voltage and controllable to be on or off for sleep mode power saving.
So if it is an output from an internal regulator, regulators in general need bypass capacitors on their outputs even if they are unused - for example you have a switch to enable power. Regulators without output capacitance may be unstable and oscillate, which is not a good idea if you want all parts of a circuit to behave well even if you don't use all parts of a circuit.
If it powers internal components as well, such as the SPI IO pins which must use the same voltage as the external SPI Flash chip, then there is already internal circuitry powered by this pin and then this pin is simply used for external bypass cap connection.
This is how many other chips with internal regulators powering internal circuitry works. You have the LDO output on some pin which needs a capacitor, and maybe even external connections to the chip inputs, which lets you decide if you use the internal regulator or provide the supply with external regulator.

Assuming the C3 is the same as the S3, that pin is the power supply pin for internal AND external flash.
If you use the chip with ONLY external flash AND it has power supplied externally then you can use it as a general purpose GPIO, so probably leaving it open with it in the default mode will be okay.
Reference here
